# jQuery Ajax Call to JSON not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

I've got this code, I'm doing a ajax jquery call to json... It works in everything but IE.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/session/json.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "",
            success: function(data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            obj.sli_cart_count = parseFloat(obj.sli_cart_count);
            obj.sli_customer_islogged = parseFloat(obj.sli_customer_islogged);
```

I did some googling and I changed it to

```
    jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/session/json.php",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: "GET",
            data: "",
            success: function(data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            obj.sli_cart_count = parseFloat(obj.sli_cart_count);
            obj.sli_customer_islogged = parseFloat(obj.sli_customer_islogged);
```

And Yay, it worked in IE.

However making that change broke it in all the other browsers.

I then tried:

```
  if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
```

Do the bottom one, else { do the top one.

This also did not work, it seemed to work in all browsers apart from IE again.

Has anyone else come across this error? any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks heaps.

Comment: What is the purpose of `data: ""`?

Comment: `contentType: "application/json"` means that what you're ***sending*** (from the client to the server) is JSON. It clearly isn't, so you should remove that as a starting point.

Comment: I'm not to sure, I can probably delete that section... I didn't write the code I'm just trying to fix it.

Comment: What version of IE are you testing in?

Comment: IE 8, 9 and 10... all doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly does "did not work" mean? Have you tried watching the HTTP traffic with Fiddler or the browser's NETWORK developer tools?

Comment: Does the success() function not get called in IE? Or does it get called with the wrong value? We need more info on exactly where this is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jQuery XDomainRequest plugin](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest) -- Simply include the plugin and call your ajax request as normal.
This works for me in IE 8 and 9.
I would also recommend using [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead.